# jQuery wrap text in a span before and after br within a paragraph

Tags: jquery

As the title suggests I am wondering how I can wrap text in a span before and after br within a paragraph.

My HTML is as so...

```
<div class="blog-container">
  <div class="each-article">
    <p>Text text text <br/> text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="each-article">
    <p>Text text text <br/> text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery, which I thought would work, is

```
$('.blog-container .each-article p br').before().wrap('<span></span>');
```

What this gives me is this:

```
<div class="blog-container">
  <div class="each-article">
    <p>Text text text <br><span></span></br> text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="each-article">
    <p>Text text text <br><span></span></br> text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kKfKS/

```
$('.each-article p').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;  
    }).wrap('<span>');
});
```

References:

- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), which selects all children, including text nodes
- [Node types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) (text node is `3`)

**Edit** - The trim isn't necessary here. However, it looks like, in some cases (like if a non-text node is the first child), empty space can be treated as a text node. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M3knf/

Comment: Out of curiousity, what does this line, `&& $.trim(this.textContent).length > 0;` do?

Comment: actually ended up using this.nodeType !== 1; to select any text that is not wrapped in another element like anchor tags and/or other inner element. But thank you very much Jason, you just saved my day by mentioning it.