# Remove border-top in second line on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists, border

Is it possible **to get rid of border-top property in the second line** of a list item on hover?

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">This is a<br/>long Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

- Display:block *causes the border has the same width like the whole element*
- Display:inline-block *causes nearly same results*

[Starting Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9xvW)

---

By the help of @Pete and the others I ended up with this:

```
$('#access a').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {          
        return this.nodeType == 3; 
    }).wrap('<span></span>');
});
```

to simply wrap the `<li>` contents with `<span>` elements:

```
<!-- with the javascript -->
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
   <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="http://www.url.com"><span>Hello</span><br/><span>World</span><a/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This makes it possible to **create a hover only for the first span element** of the li element:

```
.mainmenu ul a:hover span:first-child {border-top:1px dotted #fbf9ef;}
```

[Pete's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/T9xvW/12/)

Comment: Put the border-top on the `li`...seems obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks Paulie, but border top on li uses full width, i only want to display the border with the same width of the typo in <a>

Comment: @poor is that the same length as the top line of text or the widest line of text in the anchor?

Comment: @pete: it should be the width of the text in first line

Comment: I think the only way to do that then would be to wrap the top line in a span as others have suggested but as you can't change your html directly you may have to use [a bit of js to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038552/jquery-wrap-text-in-a-span-before-and-after-br-within-a-paragraph) - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/T9xvW/12/

Comment: ok. will try that. I will check for a break, split it and wrap it. Thanks Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can separate the two line with span tag

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>This is a</span><br/><span>long Link</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

then make this in css :

```
a:hover span:first-child {border-top:1px solid}
a:hover span:last-child {border-top:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your first line in `<span>` & use this code `a:hover span{border-top:1px solid;}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean if inline-block isn't working for you; this worked for me:

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
a:hover {
    border-top:1px solid; 
    display:inline-block; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kK2bf/

Comment: Tested it with same results. The items with a second line have a full width of the border. Here is a screenshot: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/195x262q90/834/8wg0.png

Comment: I'm seeing you wanted the line just above the "typo" in <a> but I'm not seeing a typo; is there something you left out? if you want the border to be over a specific part of the text in <a> then that's a slightly different question. You'd need to specify the typo width somehow so you could target it.

Comment: Thanks Michelle. Cant specify the width of the text because it should be a dynamic length.

Comment: Right, but are you trying to set the border on the words "this is a" specifically, no matter how they wrap on the line? Or are you trying to always target the first line of text no matter what words are on it?

Comment: First Line would be nice, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Hmm. I'd say you could try ::first-line but unfortunately that doesn't apply to borders: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line I'd say you're going to have to wrap the text in a span as was suggested elsewhere.

Comment: yes, also tried that. I will go for the wrap method. Thanks for your help Michelle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo-element ::first-line.

Comment: Michelle has found that this has no effect on Links. http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line